# SQLite: updating string values

Tags: sqlite

I couldn't find any answer for my question so I'm writing.

Are there any restrictions for updating strings in SQLite database ?
I'm wondering if any new value is written into database file there could be problem for strings of different length. Isn't it ?
I anticipate that I update strings in database and their length will be different.
In such situation should I store them into files and store only file names into database ?
Please give me some optimization tips.

Comment: I dont understand your problem, in normal cases you should have your strings in your database in `VARCHAR`-columns with a fixed width like `VARCHAR(63)` so different string lengths don't really matter as long as the strings you want to store do not exceed this predefined field width. I don't know for sqlite, but I guess if they were longer than the field in that they are stored, they will just be truncated. In any case you should have an idea what could be the maximum size of strings you need to be able to store, before trying to store them ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste SQLite always uses variable-length strings and does not enforce length limits.

Comment: @CL. thx for the notice, I just saw some samples on the web and most of them used the usually seen syntax of `VARCHAR(n)`, so I just blindly assumed SQLite would respect that

Answer (score 2):

SQLite can resize field values and records dynamically, so there are no restrictions on updating strings (except for the [normal limits](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length)).